# Paramiko not closing SSH connections - Multithread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I am using `paramiko` to initiate `ssh` connections. It would appear that when running my script that once the connections have been made, they do not get closed. Instead, it takes until `TIME_WAIT` runs out before the connections are terminated. I understand that `TIME_WAIT` represents waiting for enough time to pass to be sure the remote TCP received the acknowledgment of its connection termination request.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import sys, os, string, threading
import paramiko

paramiko.util.log_to_file("paramiko.log")

cmd = "hostname"

outlock = threading.Lock()

def workon(host):

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("./key")
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host, username='user', pkey=key)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)

    with outlock:
        result = stdout.readlines()
        print "{0}".format(hostname[0])
        ssh.close()

def main():

    with open('./ip_list') as ip:
        hosts = ip.read().splitlines()

    threads = []
    for h in hosts:
        t = threading.Thread(target=workon, args=(h,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Perhaps this is normal behavior but I wanted to be certain. When running this over hundreds of IP addresses, there are a ton of sockets that stay open on the server for several minutes after the script is done.

What confuses me is that the sockets get `ESTABLISHED` when connecting, and go to `TIME_WAIT` after - even if I don't call the `close()` method. Is this expected behavior? Should I not even bother with calling the `close()` method? Is there "better" way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIME_WAIT` is the state where you -as a client- should go when cleanly closing a connection. Thus, you should wait to ensure that the other side 'saw' your `FIN/ACK`. When you abruptly quit without calling `close()` the same will happen while cleaning up.

Working directly with sockets, you can close the connection and 'immediately' release the resources (if this is what you want), but that's not recommended as per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#disconnecting). Actually what happens is that calling `close()` on a socket does not really close the socket but waits for GC to clean it up. As a consequence an `RST/ACK` packet is sent to the other side. Thus it will continue to use resources until closed by the GC and the connection won't be properly closed.

Comment: Late reply :P but thanks! I guess this is just the consequences of using a language that utilizes garbage collecting. A good read on the subject: https://engineering.imvu.com/2014/03/06/charming-python-how-to-actually-close-a-socket-by-calling-shutdown-before-calling-close/